# Wagtail Stream Image Ignoring HTML File

Tags: django, image, wagtail

I've set up a stream file and all the blocks work except image. I know I must have overlooked something obvious. The image is displayed. It just ignores the html. In my models.py, I have:

```
    content = StreamField(
    [
        ("title_and_text", blocks.TitleTextBlock()),
        ("full_rich_text", blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ("simple_rich_text", blocks.LimitedRichTextBlock()),
        ("image_float_left", blocks.ImageChooserBlock()),
    ],
    null=True,
    blank=True,
 )
```

In my page html, I have:

```
{% for block in page.content %}
    {% include_block block %}
{% endfor %}
```

All the other blocks display correctly. In my blocks.py, I have:

```
class ImageFloatLeftBlock(ImageChooserBlock):
"""Float an image to the left"""

class Meta:
    template = "streams/image_float_left_block.html"
    icon = "doc-full"
    label = "Float Image Left"
```

The html file is ignored. I put and h1 in it just to be sure. The image is being displayed. I assume it isn't looking at the streams/image_float_left_block.html file. It does work for the other fields that are set up the same way. For example, this one works:

```
class TitleTextBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
"""Title and text and nothing else."""

title = blocks.CharBlock(required=True, help_text="The heading for the block")
text = blocks.TextBlock(required=True, help_text="The body of the block")

class Meta:
    template = "streams/title_text_block.html"
    icon = "edit"
    label = "Title & Text"
```

I suspect it's the parent class in the invocation:

```
class ImageFloatLeftBlock(ImageChooserBlock):
```

I can't find anything more appropriate in the blocks import. What would be the appropriate parent class or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the StreamField definition, you haven't told it to use your custom ImageFloatLeftBlock subclass, so it's still using the basic ImageChooserBlock which doesn't have your template setting. It should be:

```
content = StreamField(
    [
        ("title_and_text", blocks.TitleTextBlock()),
        ("full_rich_text", blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ("simple_rich_text", blocks.LimitedRichTextBlock()),
        ("image_float_left", blocks.ImageFloatLeftBlock()),
    ],
    null=True,
    blank=True,
 )
```

Comment: Actually, I had it that way and it didn't display the image. That's a different problem as my test h1 text does display so I know it's being invoked.